# I can't show localhost:8081/swagger-ui.html page in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui

I have a spring boot project. I am trying to create swagger ui documents for api's. But i can not show the swagger-ui page. When i go to localhost:8081/swagger-ui.html, page shows Whitelabel error page. Also, there is 404 not found error in the console.

**application.properties**

server.port=8081
springdoc.swagger-ui.url=/swagger-ui.html

**Controller**

```
package org.example.Controller;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponse;
import org.example.Entity.Rooms;
import org.example.Service.RoomService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/room")
public class RoomDetailController {

    @Autowired
    private RoomService roomService;

    @GetMapping("/rooms")
    public List<Rooms> getAllRooms() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        return roomService.getAllRooms();
    }
    @Operation(description="return author infor by give author id")
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Successful")
    @GetMapping("/rooms/{id}")
    public Rooms getRoom(@Parameter(name="id",description = "Author id", required = true)
                             @PathVariable Integer id) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        return roomService.getRoomDetails(id);
    }
}
```

**Entity**

```
package org.example.Entity;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;


@Schema(name="Rooms", description = "Author Entity")

public class Rooms {

    private Integer id;

    private Integer how_many_person;
    private Integer price;
    @Schema(description="Name of room", example = "Orhan")

    private String description;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getHow_many_person() {
        return how_many_person;
    }

    public void setHow_many_person(Integer how_many_person) {
        this.how_many_person = how_many_person;
    }

    public Integer getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Integer price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

**Application**

```
package org.example;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.OpenAPIDefinition;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.Info;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@OpenAPIDefinition
@SpringBootApplication
public class RoomsApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RoomsApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI getOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI().info(new Info().title("BookStore API").version("1.0"));
    }
}
```

What should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the property with:

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui.html\
springdoc.swagger-ui.disable-swagger-default-url=true
```

Also, test removing the property altogether and accessing the default url: http://localhost:8081/webjars/swagger-ui/index.html